# Use DisplayFormat to show 3 decimal places

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, displayformat

I am a newbie to .NET.  I cannot figure out the correct syntax to show three decimal places in my view.

In my model I currently have:

```
&lt;<Display(name:="Straight Rate")>
Public Property StraighRate() As Decimal
    Get
        Return mStraightRate
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
        mStraightRate = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I know I need to use the DisplayFormat in my model, but I cannot figure out the syntax that will make it work.

Do I need to do anything additional in my View after I add the syntax for the DisplayFormat in my model?

Here is what I have in my current view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) currentItem.StraightRate)
```

Comment: you should always have a String method which returns it in the correct format and use that to bind to the UI (unless of course you are editing/input) Have the String method do the formatting and return the value with formatting back.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx,
As I understand you need the format `"0.000"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `DisplayFormatAttribute`. The `DataFormatString` property determines how the value is displayed in a `DisplayTemplate`

```
<Display(name:="Straight Rate")>
<DisplayFormat(DataFormatString:="{0:0.000}")>
Public Property StraighRate() As Decimal
```

Answer (score 0):

`mStraightRate = Format(value, ##.##.##)`
you can use the Pound signs how you wish for currency you can simply put..
`mStraightRate = Format(value,"currency")`
there are more options but for custom use the top.

Comment: sorry noticed you wanted 3 decimal place here is that code. `mStraightRate = Format(value, ##.###)`

Comment: I tried upating my model to include the above:    <br/>Public Property StraighRate() As Decimal
        Get
            Return mStraightRate
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
            mStraightRate = Format(value, ##.###)
        End Set
    End Property <br/>  I am getting a build error saying expression expected....

Comment: hmm try mStraightRate.Value =